# WCF Endpoint configuration for service hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, wcf-binding

My team and I have been working on this for the past several days but have not been able to resolve it. This is our query:
Three binding parameters, maxBufferPoolSize, maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize were included in basicHttpBinding configuration as below:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ABCBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

And included the binding in the endpoint configuration:

```
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="XYZ">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ABCBinding"
          contract="ABC"/>
```

We have a really large input file which we send from Client which brought us to the issue in the first place. The file was getting sent only on the below cases:

1) The binding had no name.

2) In protocol mapping when the binding configuration was specified as below:

```
<protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="ABCBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
```

What I doubt is that the Endpoint configuration is not taken at all. Because as stated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/simplified-configuration in this link-

> If you do not add a "service" section or add any endpoints in a
>   "service" section and your service does not programmatically define
>   any endpoints, then a set of default endpoints are automatically added
>   to your service, one for each service base address and for each
>   contract implemented by your service.
>    To create default endpoints the service host must know what bindings
>   to use. These settings are specified in a "protocolMappings" section
>   within the "system.serviceModel" section. The "protocolMappings"
>   section contains a list of transport protocol schemes mapped to
>   binding types.

and

> If no bindingConfiguration is specified, the anonymous binding
>   configuration of the appropriate binding type is used.

The configuration works when the binding name is removed or when the name is specified in protocol mapping.

So does this mean that the endpoint specified is not taken into consideration?

Please help me with this issue.